# Is it possible to use multiple monitors or displays?

Tags: display

If it's possible to use multiple monitors with the device, how can this be set up and configured?

Comment: Are there USB to VGA adapters that might help achieve this goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost seven years after this question was asked, Raspberry Pi 4 includes support for dual displays.

From [Raspberry Pi 4 product page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/):

> with Raspberry Pi 4, you can run two monitors at once — and in 4K, too!

From official specs page:

> 2 × micro-HDMI ports (up to 4kp60 supported)

Comment: Fantastic! I've updated the accepted answer to this one.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use both the HDMI and RCA outputs simultaneously.

I'm not sure, but it may be possible to use a DSI display (when it becomes available) at the same time as HDMI.

Also see [this forum thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=6450).

Comment: It's best to include information from the link to prevent link rot.

Comment: You can't use a DSI and the HDMI at the same time