# Can I use dual monitors?

Tags: video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use multiple monitors or displays?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/242/is-it-possible-to-use-multiple-monitors-or-displays)

The Pi provides two video outputs, HDMI and composite. I gather for the most part they're designed to be used separately, either one or the other.

Is it possible though, from a technical perspective, to run two separate monitor feeds over these two outputs simultaneously?

Comment: @finnw Agreed, missed that when I was creating it. Have also voted to close.

Comment: This is a useful duplicate, so I have reopened it. The question is not a bad one, so I have also voted you back to neutral. I hope this is okay.

Comment: @Jivings That is of course fine by me, though it now appears to be closed once more!